# Return BOM results in "indented" order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't really need the results indented that's just the best title I could come up with.  Any help would be most appreciated.  I have spent hours attempting do this via CTE and that appears to be the way to go but I am stuck.

EDIT: I could just sort the sample data below by the Component_Job column, however, in the real world the job numbers are random and not necessarily in any usable order.

My table contains the following:

```
Root_Job    Parent_Job  Component_Job  
1           1           1a  
1           1           1b  
1           1           1c  
1           1a          1a1  
1           1a          1a2  
1           1b          1b1  
1           1b          1b2  
2           2           2a  
2           2           2b
```

I am trying to create a view that returns the following:

```
Root_Job    Parent_Job  Component_Job
1           1           1a
1           1a          1a1
1           1a          1a2
1           1           1b
1           1b          1b1
1           1b          1b2
1           1           1c
2           2           2a
2           2           2b
```

Just To clarify the return order I am trying to achieve is:

```
1
  1a
    1a1
    1a2
  1b
    1b1
    1b2
  1c
2
  2a
  2b
```

Lastly the CTE I have been attempting but is doing nothing for me is:

```
with BOM (Root_job, parent_job, component_Job)
as
(
-- Anchor member definition
    SELECT e.Root_Job, e.Parent_Job, e.Component_Job
    FROM Bill_Of_Jobs AS e
    WHERE Root_Job = Parent_Job
    UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
    SELECT e.Root_Job, e.Parent_Job, e.Component_Job
    FROM Bill_Of_Jobs AS e
    INNER JOIN bill_of_Jobs AS d
    ON e.parent_Job = d.Component_Job
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT * from BOM
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Bill_Of_Jobs ORDER BY Component_Job` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be something useful here:

```
declare @Jobs as Table ( ParentJob VarChar(10), ComponentJob VarChar(10) );
insert into @Jobs ( ParentJob, ComponentJob ) values
  ( '1', '1a' ), ( '1', '1b' ), ( '1', '1c' ),
  ( '1a', '1a1' ), ( '1a', '1a2' ), ( '1b', '1b1' ), ( '1b', '1b2' ),
  ( '2', '2a' ), ( '2', '2b' );

select * from @Jobs;

with Roots as (
  -- Find and fudge the root jobs.
  --   Usually they are represented as children without parents, but here they are implied by the presence of children.
  select distinct 1 as Depth, ParentJob as RootJob, Cast( ParentJob as VarChar(1024) ) as Path, ParentJob, ParentJob as ComponentJob
    from @Jobs as J
    where not exists ( select 42 from @Jobs where ComponentJob = J.ParentJob ) ),
  BoM as (
  -- Anchor the indented BoM at the roots.
  select Depth, RootJob, Path, ParentJob, ComponentJob
    from Roots
  union all
  -- Add the components one level at a time.
  select BoM.Depth + 1, BoM.RootJob, Cast( BoM.Path + '»' + J.ComponentJob as VarChar(1024) ), J.ParentJob, J.ComponentJob
    from BoM inner join
      @Jobs as J on J.ParentJob = BoM.ComponentJob )
  -- Show the result with indentation.
  select *, Space( Depth * 2 ) + ComponentJob as IndentedJob
    from BoM
    order by ComponentJob
    option ( MaxRecursion 0 );
```

In the *real world* it is rare to have things that sort that easily. The trick for numeric items (1, 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.2) is to create a `Path` that has each value zero-padded to a fixed length, e.g. `0001`, `0001»0001`, `0001»0001»0001`, `0001»0002`, so that they sort correctly when alphabetized. Your data may vary.

Comment: I modified the above to suit my needs and changed the order by to Path and it works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM BOM
ORDER BY LEFT(Component_Job+'000',3)
```